# How to read/write 3-dimensional information from/into multiple files?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to store my map into multiple files and be able to get that data later on. The map is sort of infinite, noise generated map. The map is chopped into chunks. Noise generation arguments has a seedvalue + XYZ so I can easily regenerate that same chunk again. Each chunk has its own c# script which has 3-dimensional bytearray map[x,y,z] and the value will tell me what block belongs to that spot. XYZ coords are world coords and not chunk coords, meaning there won't be same map[x,y,z] value even if I combine all of them together.

I want this app to be available also in mobile platforms so I want to generate map in my apps dedicated server and send chunk data over network when requested. While this reduces CPU usage of clients it also gives me extra security against hacks. (I can run checks if player is loading chunks validly, players wont be able to scan whole map and see where all good stuff is, etc.)

I read about storing a multidimensional bytearray into the file and read from it later. I can easily get chunks XYZ position and put it into filename so that for example chunks 0,0,0 data will be written into chunk_0_0_0.chunk file. I can store that chunks data to the file since I know chunks size and its position.

This is my current untested code:

```
            // Check if chunk 0,0,1 exists, if not then nothing has been yet generated!
            if(!File.Exists("world\\chunk_0_0_1.chunk")){
                generateChunk(0,0,1);
                saveMapToFile();
            }

            foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("world\\", "*.chunk"))
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("world\\" + file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    byte[,,] tempArray = (byte[,,])formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                }
            }
            return true;
```

I have a byte (`public static byte[,,] map; map[0,0,1] = 0; map[0,1,1] = 4;` etc) where I want to store EVERY chunks data so clients can easily get one piece of map and its type.  As this is infinite terrain, the map will grow overtime when players explore more. Since I can't resize byte and add more values to it, I need something else. I need something that can store each blocks position and its value. I can't use List or Dictionary since they don't support 3-dimensional. I need something where I can change the values since players will be changing the world. Problem is: what?

Comment: What is the range of values for x,y,z within a chunk? Also do I understand correctly that you store 1 byte worth of data for each position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply store the block type bytes in a regular byte array in x,z,y order. Then you can get the index for any block within the array by its coordinates. Once you have the index into the array you can get and set block type values with the index. Here is an example:

```
public class Chunk
{
    // Maximum values for directions within a chunk.
    // Change these to suit your implementation
    private static readonly byte _xLength = 32;
    private static readonly byte _yLength = 32;
    private static readonly byte _zLength = 32;

    private byte[] _buffer;

    // For creating a brand new Chunk
    public Chunk()
    {
        _buffer = new byte[_xLength * _yLength * _zLength];
    }

    // Used by Load();
    private Chunk(byte[] buffer)
    {
        _buffer = buffer;
    }

    // Loads a Chunk from file
    public static Chunk Load(string filePath)
    {
        return new Chunk(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
    }

    // Saves the Chunk to file
    public void Save(string filePath)
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, _buffer);
    }

    // Gets a value in the buffer for coordinate 
    public byte GetBlock(byte x, byte y, byte z)
    {
        int offset = GetOffset(x, y, z);

        return _buffer[offset];
    }

    // Sets a value in the buffer for coordinate 
    public void SetBlock(byte x, byte y, byte z, byte value)
    {
        int offset = GetOffset(x, y, z);

        _buffer[offset] = value;
    }

    // Get the location in the buffer for coordinate
    private static int GetOffset(byte x, byte y, byte z)
    {
        return (y * _xLength * _zLength) + (z * _xLength) + x;            
    }
}
```

And then some tests..

```
static void Main()
{
    // Create a new Chunk
    Chunk chunk1 = new Chunk();

    // Set some block types in the chunk
    chunk1.SetBlock(1, 1, 1, 11);
    chunk1.SetBlock(2, 2, 2, 22);
    chunk1.SetBlock(3, 3, 3, 33);

    // Save it to disk
    chunk1.Save("test.chunk");

    // Load from disk
    Chunk chunk2 = Chunk.Load("test.chunk");

    Console.WriteLine("Block at ({0},{1},{2}): {3}", 1, 1, 1, chunk2.GetBlock(1, 1, 1));
    Console.WriteLine("Block at ({0},{1},{2}): {3}", 2, 2, 2, chunk2.GetBlock(2, 2, 2));
    Console.WriteLine("Block at ({0},{1},{2}): {3}", 3, 3, 3, chunk2.GetBlock(3, 3, 3));

}
```